# LAG() and timestamps

Tags: google-bigquery

Possible BigQuery bug here? I'm running a query that uses the LAG() function to get the previous timesamp value. Example:

schema:

```
id: STRING
time: TIMESTAMP
```

query:

```
SELECT id, 
time as current_time, LAG(time,1) OVER (PARTITION BY id, order by time) as previous_time
FROM dataset.table
```

While "current_time" comes back as a timestamp value, "previous_time" comes back as an integer value. e.g.:

```
"12345", "2014-04-09 00:19:01 UTC", 1396992237000000
```

Any ideas on how to get LAG() return a TIMESTAMP?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is indeed a bug (I've filed it internally). This is leaking the internal representation of the timestamp, which is in microseconds.

You can work around this by using the `USEC_TO_TIMESTAMP()` function. As in:

```
SELECT id, 
time as current_time, 
USEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(LAG(time,1) OVER (PARTITION BY id, order by time)) as previous_time
FROM dataset.table
```

That said, this will break once we fix the bug. If you want to be notified when it is fixed, you can file it at the BigQuery public issue tracker [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/).

Comment: Unfortunately, BQ doesn't like me putting USEC_TO_TIMESTAMP around the LAG statement. Getting this:  

Error: Encountered " "OVER" "OVER "" at line 9, column 36. Was expecting: ")" ... 

Also, can you provide a direct link to the bug? Wasn't able to find it using search.

Comment: Never mind my last question about direct link - I misread your statement ;-) Thanks!

Comment: That bug does not seem to be fixed yet. I get back something that looks like a timestamp, however I cannot perform any timestamp operation on it such as TIMESTAMP_TO_USEC.