# BigQuery: Selecting the smallest difference among fields in a repeated record

Tags: google-bigquery

Consider this table schema on BigQuery:

```
Table User
{
user_id: STRING (REQUIRED)
user_name: STRING (REQUIRED)
actions: RECORD (REPEATED) 
    {
        action_id: STRING (REQUIRED)
        action_type: INTEGER (REQUIRED)
        action_date: TIMESTAMP (REQUIRED)
    }
}
```

I want to find all Users (user_id and user_name) who created some type of action more than once, and the smallest time between those actions were less than X days.

The number of stored actions per User is not defined (can be 1, 2, or n). The actions are not sorted by any criteria (but I think that's solvable by using an `ORDER BY`).

For example, with the users:

```
{
    user_id: "u1", 
    user_name: "User 1", 
    actions: 
    {action_id: "a1", action_type: 1, action_date: "2016-02-22"},
    {action_id: "a2", action_type: 1, action_date: "2016-01-22"},
    {action_id: "a3", action_type: 1, action_date: "2015-12-22"}
},
{
    user_id: "u2", 
    user_name: "User 2", 
    actions: 
    {action_id: "a4", action_type: 1, action_date: "2016-02-22"},
    {action_id: "a5", action_type: 2, action_date: "2016-01-22"},
    {action_id: "a6", action_type: 1, action_date: "2015-12-22"}
},
{
    user_id: "u3", 
    user_name: "User 3", 
    actions: 
    {action_id: "a7", action_type: 1, action_date: "2016-02-22"}
},
{
    user_id: "u4", 
    user_name: "User 4", 
    actions: 
    {action_id: "a8", action_type: 1, action_date: "2016-02-22"},
    {action_id: "a9", action_type: 1, action_date: "2015-02-22"},
    {action_id: "a10", action_type: 1, action_date: "2015-01-22"}
},
```

The query "select users that executed actions of type `1` more than once, and the smallest time between each execution was less than `45` days" should return `User 1` and `User 4`.

Any ideas on how to do that on BigQuery?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I didn't mark as accepted yet because i didn't have the time to test it, so please be patient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below
Written on go and thus not tested, but I feel it should work and do what you need

```
SELECT 
  user_id, 
  user_name, 
  action_type, 
  MIN(DATEDIFF(action_date_next, action_date)) AS min_distance
FROM (
  SELECT 
    user_id, 
    user_name, 
    action_type, 
    action_date, 
    LAG(action_date) 
        OVER(PARTITION BY user_id, action_type 
        ORDER BY action_date DESC) AS action_date_next
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      user_id, 
      user_name, 
      actions.action_type AS action_type, 
      actions.action_date AS action_date 
    FROM table_users 
  )
)
WHERE action_date_next IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY user_id, user_name, action_type
HAVING action_type = 1 AND min_distance < 45
```

Below version is more compact - try it too

```
SELECT 
  user_id, 
  user_name, 
  action_type, 
  MIN(DATEDIFF(action_date_next, action_date)) AS min_distance
FROM (
  SELECT 
    user_id, 
    user_name, 
    actions.action_type AS action_type, 
    actions.action_date AS action_date, 
    LAG(actions.action_date) 
        OVER(PARTITION BY user_id, actions.action_type 
        ORDER BY actions.action_date DESC) AS action_date_next
  FROM table_users
)
WHERE action_date_next IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY user_id, user_name, action_type
HAVING action_type = 1 AND min_distance < 45
```

Comment: There's a bug with the LAG function and TIMESTAMPs on BigQuery, take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25054216/lag-and-timestamps). Aside from that the answer seems to solve to problem, I'll accept it once I can test properly.